# Facing issues in create new list from string item with brackets and percentages

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have one array that showed in x:

```
x=['T','0(99%)','2','0','8(56%)','0','0','0']
```

I want to get as:

```
target=[0,2,0,8,0,0,0]
```

How to extract numbers from such group of values and also how can it do with many lists in a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
x = ['T','0(99%)','2','0','8(56%)','0','0','0']
output = [item[0] for item in x if item[0].isdigit()]
```

output is: `['0', '2', '0', '8', '0', '0', '0']`

doing it in a loop:

```py
out_list_of_lists = []
for x in list_of_lists:
    out_list_of_lists.append([item[0] for item in x if item[0].isdigit()])
```

you can even do a nested list comprehension if that's your thing:

```py
out_list_of_lists = [[item[0] for item in x if item[0].isdigit()] for x in list_of_lists]
```

Comment: Ok Thanks!!
But When I tried to do with:
x=['RX', ':', '0(', '0%)', '2(', '0%)', '0(', '0%)', '154018(', '99%)', '0(', '0%)', '0(', '0%)', '0(', '0%)']
I could not solve the above:
My target array is:
target=[0,2,0,154018,0,0,0]

Comment: Are all the "number" items in the list in the form of "number(...)"? If so, you can change the list comprehension to be `output = [item.split("(")[0] for item in x if item.split("(")[0].isdigit()]` - the change is splitting by the opening parantheses